# Accessing Inner class Variable for Switch Button

Tags: android, switch-statement

I am trying to wrap `switchbutton` in function and return the value based upon the switch is `checked` /`unchecked`, but due to the java design restriction, I have to declare the string as final, I don't want the return value as final as it changes based upon the selection,

**Below is my code**

```
protected String getSwitchValue(Switch sw){
     String ReturnValue; // Issue in accessing the variable in inner class
    sw.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        //String ReturnValue;
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked){
                ReturnValue = "Yes"; // throws error here 
            }else {
                ReturnValue = "No";  // throws error here 
            }
        }
    });
    return ReturnValue;
}
```

Comment: move `String ReturnValue;` outside `getSwitchValue` or call some method from chechchange directly

Answer (score 0):

You are right that you can't do it this way. You can get this accomplished without the `setOnCheckedChangeListener()` like below.

```
protected String getSwitchValue(Switch sw) {
    if (sw.isChecked()) {
        return "YES";
    } else {
        return "NO";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your "getSwitchValue" method seem to want to get the current switch button state? If so you want to use "Switch.isChecked()" instead of a listener.

OnCheckedChangeListener is what you need when you want to trigger some event handling when you change the checked state of switch button. Not when you want to get the current state.